# Using Plupload to upload files, browse_button stops working

Tags: javascript, plupload

I have found that when the browse_button gets moved on the screen (possibly due to dynamic content), it doesn't work anymore and needs a Uploader.refresh() call (mentioned on the plupload forum).

I have been working around the issue by adding the refresh to the various effects callbacks:

```
$(".flash").fadeOut(3000, function(){
    uploader.refresh();
});
```

Unfortunately, I have jquery fadeIn/out everywhere, what would be a good way to avoid needing to call this function all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this was to put the upload link inside of a div, thus making the location of the upload link relative to the div that it is in.